# Grails Restfull Json Problems in Controller

Tags: json, rest, grails, groovy, controller

I have a problem with `REST` json service.I have problems with all REST operations (POST, PUT, DELETE, GET). I need to have IF-else statements in each operation but something is going wrong. For example, in the GET operation, I need to have some if-else cases.I want `findByName` or by `id` or with which ever fields. My program works ok when I use only one case(only one if). If I use multiple if-else statements the program doesn't work. I have the same problem with `DELETE`. What am I doing wrong? What should be done?

THANKS

```
def index = {
    switch (request.method) {

        case "POST":
            def trip = new Trip(params.trip)

            if (trip.save()) {
                response.status = 201 // Created
                render trip as JSON
            } else {
                response.status = 500 //Internal Server Error
                render "Could not create new Trip due to errors:\n ${trip.errors}"
            }
            break
        case "GET":
            if (params.city) render Trip.findByCity(params.city) as JSON

            // else if(params.name)render Trip.findByName(params.name) as JSON
            //else if(params.city)render Trip.findByCity(params.city)as JSON
            // else render Trip.list() as JSON
            break
        case "PUT":
            def trip = Trip.get(params.name)
            trip.properties = params.Trip
            if (trip.save()) {
                response.status = 200 // OK
                render trip as JSON
            } else {
                response.status = 500 //Internal Server Error
                render "Could not create new Trip due to errors:\n ${trip.errors}"
            }
            break
            break
        case "DELETE":
            if (params.name) {
                def trip = Trip.findByName(params.name)
                if (trip) {
                    trip.delete()
                    render "Successfully Deleted."
                } else {
                    response.status = 404 //Not Found
                    render "${params.name} not found."
                }
            } else {
                response.status = 400 //Bad Request
                render """DELETE request must include the NAME code
                  Example: /rest/airport/name
        """
                break
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you standardized your indents it would be easier for would-be-helpers to see what's going on.  Even better, that might be enough for you to see for yourself where it's broken, since it sounds a lot like an error in logic nesting.

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: So is this the code that works?  Or the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi!The code works.My problem is this:I have a program to make rest request and my code has a postgreesql table.ok?What I want, for example, is that I ask a GET of a row of the table and I return that row in a json.I want to look for that get by field (name, id ... whatever..)and my problem is that when testing with my program get a request, only get it to work the search for a single field (eg you can only search the table by name) If I put in an if-else search by name if not id ...

Comment: I no longer work when executing the request and the request nothing happens. I do not understand because if a field search only works for me and if I put that can be searched by various not work.Like what I can do to put several instances of search? Same here in petitions Delete.
thanks

Comment: Somebody PLEASE¿??????????I have to give my code in a proyect :(!